# Video on website with autoplay ? Alternative

Tags: html, ios, video, html5-video, autoplay

I've been working on a new website for a couple days now and I've seen that autoplay video will not be supported anymore on safari mobile. I've checked that on my phone and for a couple months I get weird behaviors on my videos. Some videos don't autoplay anymore and some others are autoplaying but with a player above. (I can only relate to my experience on IOS devices).

Would like to know if there's any real alternative to solve this issue in the long term by using another method?

I only use autoplay video for small video that loop (15 seconds max), but GIF images are not high quality enough.

Hope this topic will help people to find the right solution for this issue !

Thank you in advanced ! 
PS : My English is not really perfect, I'm not a native speaker !

Answer (score 0):

You cant really do much about this, since its a decision from Apple.

In general id recommend not to use autoplay videos in the first case since they cost a lot of performance and can be rather confusing for a visitor that maybe doesnt even want to so a video. Especially when the video is with audio, this scares every user away.

If you are using the video in the background you got two option:

1. You use a GIF, but as you already noted it will be a lower quality
2. You use a Javascript to inform the user that he should enable autoplay for videos in the background (Which is a setting is Safari)

For the second option i found this solution in the internet:

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.catch(error => {
        // Auto-play was prevented
        // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback
    }).then(() => {
        // Auto-play started
    });
}
```

Source: https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

Answer (score 0):

It's an HTML 5 video autoplay policy. You can't autoplay video with sound.

Muted autoplay is always allowed.

Comment: Hey ! I tried but I get a player above with this method.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```html
<video autoplay>
  <source src="https://multicdn.synq.fm/projects/bb/56/bb56f28429b942c08dc5128e4b7ba48c/derivatives/videos/71/43/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc/mp4_1080/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc_mp4_1080.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

---

You can insert loop (if you want), controls (for seek bar etc), muted (if you want) next to the video word.

> `<video autoplay controls loop muted>`

Example with no controls:

```html
<video autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="https://multicdn.synq.fm/projects/bb/56/bb56f28429b942c08dc5128e4b7ba48c/derivatives/videos/71/43/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc/mp4_1080/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc_mp4_1080.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Also check [this](https://blog.synq.fm/html5-video-looping-autoplay-on-ios-and-android) out.